# What does the return value of a priority queue custom comparator signify?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, comparator

From what I could gather about a custom comparator for a priority queue of the following structure, it looks like this

```
struct event
{
    int index, arrival, duration, type, end;
};

struct compare
{
    bool operator() (event a, event b)
    {
        if (a.arrival < b.arrival) return true; // which one gets pushed first?
        else return false;
    }
};
...
priority_queue < event, vector <event>, compare > pq;
```

What I did not understand is the meaning of returning `true` or `false`. If I return `true`, which element gets pushed first to the queue, and which, if I return `false`?

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Comment: Your `operator()` is broken. It should *always* return something.

Comment: The easy way to do it would be `return a.arrival < b.arrival;`

Comment: @SergeyA That tells you that `Compare` has to be a strict weak ordering - it doesn't tell you in what direction the result is used, right?

Comment: @Barry, it also requires the knowledge of priority_queue being max heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` is a *max* heap, which by default uses `std::less` (which is a function object which uses `operator<`). That implies that if the comparison returns `false`, the first argument goes closer to the top. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time lookup of the **largest (by default)** element, at the expense of logarithmic insertion and extraction.
>
> A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g. using `std::greater<T>` would cause the smallest element to appear as the `top()`.

The standard reference is [[alg.heap.operations]](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.heap.operations#1).

---

Side-note #1: Avoid writing `if (expr) return true; else return false;` in favor of simply `return expr;`

Side-note #2: Your `operator()` should be a `const` member function and take its arguments by reference to `const` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: If the comparison returns false, the second argument goes closer to the top, right?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't quite get it. So I commented. I'll probably just close the question...

Comment: @AnukulSangwan What part of the first two sentences of my answer is not clear?

Comment: I'm not overloading the `<` operator by using `bool operator()` , right? So, I can't relate to the first two lines.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan No. The two are unrelated.

Comment: I just want to know what the result of the return value of my `bool operator()` comparator will be. I can't see how knowing about the max heap nature of a priority queue helps me understand that.

Comment: Nitpick: Side note #1 depends on the nature of `expr`.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, but I'm still going to leave that part as-is :)

Comment: @Barry Fine with me ;)

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Think about how you would implement a max heap if the only operation you were allowed to use is `<`. Given `x<y` being `true`, which element goes on top? `priority_queue` follows those exact rules, just extrapolated out to `cmp(x,y)` instead. And which part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: Okay. In a max heap, the elements with larger values are at the top, so `x<y` being true means that `y` goes to the top, right? But I'm not using `bool operator<` here ... I don't understand how it is extrapolated to `cmp(x, y)`. I think that the max heap wouldn't know whether the `true` result of `cmp(x, y)` means `x<y` or `x>y` as the operator (`<, >`) is not mentioned.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan It doesn't matter which comparison `cmp` does, as long as it establishes a valid ordering. If `cmp(x,y)` returns `true`, that means `y` is "larger" based on that comparison, so it goes to the top. (Note that "larger" here is only in reference to the comparison, not which value actually compares bigger with `>`)

Comment: @AnukulSangwan And really, you could've just... tried it and seen what happens.